# C# Grade Calculator

Tags: c#, calculator

I'm currently coding a grades calculator that adds 3 test scores and gives you a letter grade depending on the average. So far I have been able to code everything without any issues except for one thing. In this calculator I added a checkbox that drops the lowest grade and averages out the highest 2 if checked. I just started programming a few weeks ago and have no idea how begin coding this. Should I use an if statement or a loop? If you guys have any tips on eliminating unnecessary code or anything else, feel free to point it out.

```
 public frmGradeCalculator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }




    private void chkDropLowest_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear Text

        txtTest1.Clear();
        txtTest2.Clear();
        txtTest3.Clear();
        txtAverage.Clear();
        txtLetterGrade.Clear();

        // Set Focus

        txtTest1.Focus();
    }

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Declare variables

        byte bytTest1;
        byte bytTest2;
        byte bytTest3;
        float fltAverage;
        string strLetterGrade = "F";

        // Convert to text

        if (byte.TryParse(txtTest1.Text, out bytTest1))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Number!",
                "Yancarlos Grade Calculator",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            txtTest1.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (byte.TryParse(txtTest2.Text, out bytTest2))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Number!",
                "Yancarlos Grade Calculator",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            txtTest2.Focus();
            return;
        }
        if (byte.TryParse(txtTest3.Text, out bytTest3))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Number!",
                "Yancarlos Grade Calculator",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            txtTest3.Focus();
            return;
        }

        // Formula 

        fltAverage = (bytTest1 + bytTest2 + bytTest3) / 3;

        if (fltAverage <= 59.9)
        {
            strLetterGrade = "F";
        }
        else if (fltAverage <= 63.9)
        {
            strLetterGrade = "D-";
        }
        else if (fltAverage <= 66.9)
        {
            strLetterGrade = "D";
        }
        else if (fltAverage <= 69.9)
        {
            strLetterGrade = "D+";
        }
        else if (fltAverage <= 73.9)
        {
            strLetterGrade = "C-";
        }
        else if (fltAverage <= 76.9)
        {
            strLetterGrade = "C";
        }
        else if (fltAverage <= 79.9)
        {
            strLetterGrade = "C+";
        }
        else if (fltAverage <= 83.9)
        {
            strLetterGrade = "B-";
        }
        else if (fltAverage <= 86.9)
        {
            strLetterGrade = "B";
        }
        else if (fltAverage <= 89.9)
        {
            strLetterGrade = "B+";
        }
        else if (fltAverage <= 93.9)
        {
            strLetterGrade = "A-";
        }
        else if (fltAverage <= 96.9)
        {
            strLetterGrade = "A";
        }
        else 
        {
            strLetterGrade = "A+";
        }



        // convert back to user

        txtAverage.Text = fltAverage.ToString("f1");
        txtLetterGrade.Text = strLetterGrade.ToString();

    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Exit application

        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void frmGradeCalculator_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question on whether to use a loop or an if statement, all checkbox controls have a Checked property that you can check.

```
if(chkDropLowest.Checked)
{
       //Calculate average without the lowest test
}
```

As far as design goes, I would recommend that you not assign so much functionality to a specific button. I would instead create a new method to call from that button (that way you are safe if you ever decide to use a new control in the future)

Example:

```
private string CalculateLetterGrade(byte test1, byte test2, byte test3)
{
     string letterGrade;

     if(chkDropLowest.Checked)
     { 
          //Drop lowest test then calculate average
     }
     else
     {
          //Use all tests then calculate average
     }

     //Determine the string for the letter grade, then return it

     return letterGrade;
}
```

You seem to have the average logic worked out so I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on not assigning to much functionality to one button, i will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot when you go to calculate the average:

```
double totalScore = bytTest1 + bytTest2 + bytTest3;
double lowest = Math.Min(Math.Min(bytTest1, bytTest2), bytTest3);
if (chkDropLowest.IsChecked == true)
{
    // Drop the lowest test
    fltAverage = (totalScore - lowest) / 2;
}
else
{
    // Include all three tests
    fltAverage = (totalScore) / 3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly! I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: You bet. As others have mentioned, consider breaking these bits of 'functionality' into their own methods. I.e., a `CalculateScore(List<double> scores, bool dropLowest)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little bit for interest sake I've refactored your `btnCalculate_Click`. This solves your problem, but I've posted it more so that you can have a look at code that more tersely solves your problem and maybe give you some syntax to look at.

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Func<TextBox, double?> parseTextBox = tb =>
    {
        double value;
        if (!double.TryParse(tb.Text, out value))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Number!",
                "Yancarlos Grade Calculator",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            tb.Focus();
            return null;
        }
        return value;
    };

    double?[] tests =
    (
        from tb in new[] { txtTest3, txtTest2, txtTest1, }
        let result = parseTextBox(tb)
        orderby result descending
        select result
    ).ToArray();

    if (tests.Any(t => t == null))
    {
        return;
    }

    double average =
        tests
            .Take(3 - (checkBox1.Checked ? 1 : 0))
            .Average()
            .Value;

    var grades = new[]
    {
        new { Score = 59.9, Grade = "F" },
        new { Score = 63.9, Grade = "D-" },
        new { Score = 66.9, Grade = "D" },
        new { Score = 69.9, Grade = "D+" },
        new { Score = 73.9, Grade = "C-" },
        new { Score = 76.9, Grade = "C" },
        new { Score = 79.9, Grade = "C+" },
        new { Score = 83.9, Grade = "B-" },
        new { Score = 86.9, Grade = "B" },
        new { Score = 89.9, Grade = "B+" },
        new { Score = 93.9, Grade = "A-" },
        new { Score = 96.9, Grade = "A" },
        new { Score = 100.0, Grade = "A+" },
    };

    string grade =
        grades
            .Where(g => g.Score >= average)
            .Select(g => g.Grade)
            .First();

    txtAverage.Text = average.ToString("f1");
    txtLetterGrade.Text = grade;
}
```

Comment: This code looks great! i appreciate the help i still have a lot to learn so some of the code i am not familiar with. I will keep this and look back at it when i learn a little bit more and go aha! Thanks again!